# Sync cookies in multiple WKWebViews on iOS 9

Tags: ios, swift, cookies, wkwebview

I am using 2 ViewControllers with 2 WKWebViews.

The WebViews use a shared WKWebViewConfiguration.
extension WKWebViewConfiguration {

```
static var Shared : WKWebViewConfiguration{
    if sharedConfiguration == nil{
        sharedConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        sharedConfiguration.websiteDataStore = WKWebsiteDataStore.default()
        sharedConfiguration.processPool = WKProcessPool()
    }
    return sharedConfiguration
}

private static var sharedConfiguration : WKWebViewConfiguration!
```

}

I am passing this on each webView and from what I read this should be the solution for shared Cookies.

But because I am doing a login though the webContent I want to have the webViews **SYNCHED** if the user is logged in or not.

The problem happens when the user **logs in**. The steps that I follow are the :

1) I have identify the host and the path, and checking the `navigationAction.request.url.host` and `navigationAction.request.url.path`
when the user makes a request, and the request happens **ONLY** if the credentials are correct (So I know the correct host and path) I create a bool var that indicates that the users has **logged in**

2) After the WebView didFinish : FINISH , I call a func that reloads the webViews that have to get *refreshed*  but the WebViews are not acting like they have the cookies.

3) after some seconds(different everytime) ,adding manual the code .reload() the web views in each preview , the webViews are synched.

I am working on iOS 9 since these are the requirements.

It looks that the cookies are asynced, and eventually they arrive to the shared processPool or websiteDataStore from my understanding.

Anyone have a solid solution?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to share same web configuration, you just need to share `processPool` and `KWebsiteDataStore.default()` after creating each webview configuration. To verify you can check cookies from Safari developer tool.

As @PS mentioned no workaround is working for him to sync cookies. I also encounter the same problem. but I tried some unexpected things to fix this issue and that is work 100%

Cookie sync takes some time to sync with cookie store for wkwebview. so my fix is just made dummy web request that will sync cookie on app start and after that, wherever you have to use your sign In or Sign Out call you can use without making any further modification.

Comment: It looks like that the Cookies are shared, but the problem is that if I refresh a WebView it has the cookies, but it takes some seconds to get updated. Did you ever face and similar problem?

Comment: only first time application install I face this type of issue. cookie sync took some time. but after that, there should be no issue

Comment: Since I am dealing with a login/logout integrated button on WebContext , I am having a 5-10 second delay to synch the Cookies(if this is the issue) and show the correct state of the Login/Logout . Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: one thing you are facing all time delay ? if yes then its diff issue. if only once then can be fix

Comment: No I am facing all the time a delay. any Suggestions?

Comment: How you are synching cookies ?

Comment: I have a singleton of WKprocessPool() and WKWebSiteDataStore.default() and I am passing on the configuration of each WKWebView when I am setting up the WKWebViews

Comment: You must set process pool and datastore to default

Comment: If cookie sync one time then you dont need to syncing again

Comment: I have set a singleton for processPool and websitedatastore.default() is that the recommended?

Comment: class WebViewStorage {
    
    static let shared = WebViewStorage()
    
    private init(){}
    
    var sharedPool = WKProcessPool()
    var sharedDataStore = WKWebsiteDataStore.default()
}

Comment: Yes it required

Comment: Then since I have this setup it should work , but still I get a delay every time

Comment: Unfortunately this is impossible. But thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @PS did you fixed issue ?

Comment: I kinda fixed it. I had to make the request passing the cookies manually. But still is not 100% stable.

Comment: one thing that you can do, before make request pass cookies and before sending request just check cookie exist in wkwebview httpcookiestore or not. if yes then send request.

Comment: Let me know if you got better solution @PS

Comment: I had a fix for this problem. its tricky but solved problem 100%

Comment: I just collect the cookies from the response after the login var cookies = [String : String]() , and I just past them on the request manually of the page I wanted to refresh and show the login status. It is 99.5% on the correct state when it does the refreshes the page , but sometimes it needs a second time refresh to show the correct state. I believe it has to do something with the back end also. Any better solution ?

Comment: Add some dealy in request

Comment: Yeah I tried that but Since I can't be sure how much the delay will be, I just refresh the page every time. Delay won't be correct in case of bad connection. For this specific case I would suggest that refreshing every time is the best solution.

Comment: can you try one thing load your webview in ui thread and before loading webview withing ui thread block check cookies are set ? i suspect in UI block cookies not sync properly

Comment: Thanks man. I will try that in case I continue with that issue. I will let you know. But you could post that solution as a correct answer so more people can have access on knowledge like your solution !!!